# C# Selenium Firefox WebDriver throws error, when trying to use socks5 proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, socks

I have installed with the nuget, a package with firefox driver and selenium.

WebDriver 3.10.0.0, firefox used is 58.0.2 (x64)

I use this code:

```
public class SeleniumWorker
{
        IWebDriver ffBaseDriver = null;
        INavigation ffBaseNavigator = null;
        string proxy, referer;
        public SeleniumWorker(string proxy,string referer)
        {
            this.proxy = proxy;
            this.referer = referer;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy))
            {
                this.ffBaseDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            else
            {
                FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                ffOptions.Proxy = new Proxy { SocksProxy = proxy };
                this.ffBaseDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);
            }
        }

        public void DoAction(Object param)
        {
            this.ffBaseDriver.Navigate();
            this.ffBaseNavigator.GoToUrl(this.referer);
        }
}
.....
// somewhere in code:
worker = new SeleniumWorker("127.0.0.1:9050","https://google.com");
worker.DoAction();
```

When the FFoptions is set here `this.ffBaseDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);` i get an Exception like this:

`InvalidArgumentError: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be an integer (SessionNotCreated)`

And stack trace:

```
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   в OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
   в Br30AutoReg.SeleniumReger..ctor(String proxy, String refererd) в C:\Users\pashok\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Test\Test\SeleniumWorker.cs:строка 34
   в Br30AutoReg.ControlThread.RegistrationLoop(Object obj) в C:\Users\pashok\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Test\Test\ControlThread.cs:строка 216
```

How can i set socks5 proxy then? Also i have a question i not wanna create new one, can i manipulate about:config from selenium, and disable WEBRtc?